# Filter tidy data by the cell size of its crosstab

Tags: r

Given a tidy dataset, such as this subset of mtcars:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- mtcars %>% select(cyl, gear)
head(x)
##                   cyl gear
## Mazda RX4           6    4
## Mazda RX4 Wag       6    4
## Datsun 710          4    4
## Hornet 4 Drive      6    3
## Hornet Sportabout   8    3
## Valiant             6    3
```

I want to fit a linear model, ignoring cells that have too few observations.  So in the crosstab:

```
library(tidyr)
x %>% group_by(cyl, gear) %>% summarize(n = n()) %>% spread(cyl, n)
## Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
## 
##   gear 4 6  8
## 1    3 1 2 12
## 2    4 8 4 NA
## 3    5 2 1  2
```

I would like to filter out all rows where

- `gear == 3 & cyl %in% c(4, 6)`
- `gear == 4 & cyl == 8`
- `gear == 5`

and end up with a dataset in the tidy form of the original.

How can that be done by filtering on cell size, rather than gear/cyl values?

**Note:** Any solution is welcome, not limited to `dplyr`/`tidyr` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wanted to use base R, you can get all the cyl/gear combos that have more than 2 observations with

```
subset(mtcars,
    ave(cyl, cyl, gear, FUN=length)>2)
```

Comment: The catch here is that the first argument has to be numeric.  So unless you have a numeric in the dataset already, you have to create a dummy one.

Comment: Yes. `ave()` does assume the class of the return value will match the class of the first parameter.